# SQL Server : query for instances of a bit that is 0 for all codes in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

**people**

```
    person_id int
    FirstName varchar
    LastName  varchar
```

**people_codes**

```
    person_id int
    code varchar
    primary bit
```

If I join the tables I get something like this:

```
    firstName   lastName   code   primary
    -------------------------------------
    John        Smith      GEN    0
    John        Smith      VAS    1
    Aaron       Johnson    ANE    0
    Allison     Hunt       HOS    0
```

Ok, so here's the question. How do I query for only the people that have a primary bit of only a 0?

In the above results I only want Aaron and Allison to return, because John Smith has a primary occurrence of 1. Essentially, I can't just say `where primary = 0` because I would still get John.

Thank you,

Trout

Comment: And what are the desired results? Just `firstName` and `lastName` or `code` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from people p, people_codes c where p.person_id = c.person_id and p.person_id not in (select person_id from person_codes where primary = 1)`

replace * with desired columns, include alias (p.FirstName)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM dbo.people AS p
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.people_codes
    WHERE person_id = p.person_id
    GROUP BY person_id
    HAVING MAX(CONVERT(TINYINT, [primary]) = 0)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `Not Exists` statement, like this:

```
Select FirstName, LastName
From people
    -- <optional join to other tables>
Where Not Exists
(
    Select 1
    From people_codes
    Where primary = 1
        And people.person_id = people_codes.person_id
)
```

Why do you want to you use Not Exists? See: [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Good to know. I will start using `Not Exists` from now on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select distint firstName, lastName  , code   ,primary
From people 
    Inner Join people_codes on people.person_id = people_codes.person_id 
Where people.person_id NOT IN (select person_id 
                               from people_codes 
                               where primary=1)
```